# How to pick which one to use between SASS, SCSS and LESS with create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, less, create-react-app

I have read about CSS preprocessors, and I find out to be very cool, I saw some tutorials as well about these and I want to do some hands-on and integrate it with my reactJs project which is created by using create-react-app.

As far as I have learned, both preprocessors have almost same features only there is a slight difference between syntax of both of these(I like the syntax of LESS more) and these are built on different languages(Sass on Ruby and Less on Js). I'm from Javascript background. 
I have also seen some tutorials on how to integrate less/sass in create-react-app in which I saw that, we need to do `npm run eject` and then add some configurations in Webpack file (Please suggest if there is any better way).

I don't know which one reactJs supports the most or recommended by reactJs, and which one will be easier and cleaner to work with, will be more configurable and will suit my background and if there are any advantages and disadvantages of using one over another for me?

I'm thinking that LESS would be easier for me but some people says that SASS has a large ecosystem and would be great for big projects. I'm getting really confused between these two I need guidance from your experience.
How to decide which one to pick, please give some suggestions.

Comment: SCSS/SASS works out of the box by adding `node-sass` to the project and simply renaming the files to `.scss` or `.sass`

Comment: Just pick one and run with it. they all do more or less the same thing personally scss is my choice as its used with angular and ionic and is easy enough for anyone to pick up and use.

Comment: @Deckerz If, SASS will be easier to use, do I also need to have knowledge of ruby to use it?

Comment: @4LPH4 nope, you just use it, node-sass is a JS compiler based on the ruby version.